# How to present ping data from ICMP timestamp

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, computer-networks, synchronization

The [ICMP timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Timestamp) protocol is useful for determining which path — forward or reverse — is contributing to the jitter on the line.

In an ideal world, all computers would have an excellent ntpd, and time accuracy of about 1ms (the granularity of ICMP timestamp) should not be a problem:

```
0       145.5   146 = 75 + 71
1       142.7   142 = 72 + 70
2       140.7   140 = 70 + 70
3       146.7   146 = 76 + 70
4       148.3   148 = 77 + 71
5       157.5   157 = 87 + 70
6       167.1   167 = 96 + 71
7       166.3   166 = 95 + 71
8       167.7   167 = 97 + 70
9       159.0   159 = 88 + 71
```

However, in reality, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172028/awk-hping-print-difference-between-icmp-originate-receive/20186781#20186781, the data could be like this:

```
0       165.9   166 = -142113 + 142279
1       160.2   160 = -142118 + 142278
2       155.2   155 = -142122 + 142277
3       156.5   156 = -142121 + 142277
4       164.7   165 = -142112 + 142277
5       164.4   164 = -142111 + 142275
6       160.9   161 = -142114 + 142275
7       158.1   158 = -142117 + 142275
8       155.6   156 = -142119 + 142275
9       143.0   143 = -142131 + 142274
10      153.2   153 = -142120 + 142273
11      157.1   157 = -142115 + 142272
12      158.3   158 = -142114 + 142272
13      148.6   149 = -142123 + 142272
14      144.3   144 = -142127 + 142271
15      145.3   145 = -142125 + 142270
```

Which still shows that only one path is responsible for the jitter, since only one value jumps up and down randomly, whereas the other one is decreasing monotonically (probably due to an actively-running ntpd, which is correcting the time as we ping).

Another example could be less wrong-looking of the time not being synchronised, say:

```
0       165.9   166 = -113 + 279
```

Or, better yet:

```
0       165.9   166 = 7 + 159
```

Or, say, still wrong by some 10ms to 40ms, on a landline link from Alberta to Vogtland, but much less obvious:

```
0       165.9   166 = 59 + 107
```

How to make scientific sense of this data, for it to be easily presentable, and not blatantly wrong?

Feel free to assume to have between 10 to 1000 measurement points, measured over a couple of seconds or minutes.

Comment: I think you're going to need to add something to tell us what each of those numbers means: i.e., what is the definition of the numbers in the 4 columns of those charts.  How are they measured?  What do they measure?  What are the units?

Comment: Units are ms.  Numbers are created by sending *ICMP timestamp* to remote host, receiving reply, and doing some simple arithmetic (links within the question provide extended details).  Ideally, the number in the third column is the roundtrip time, fourth is the transmission delay to remote host, and fifth is the reception delay from remote to local.  First two numbers could be ignored.  The whole problem is that wall clocks are not synchronised, so, you get negative numbers and such.  Let me know if you have any further questions, or just install `hping` and try the referenced script yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> How to make scientific sense of this data, for it to be easily presentable, and not blatantly wrong?

Well, the bottom line is: this data *is* blatantly wrong.  If your measurement method says that the latency on some link is negative 113 ms, there is something wrong with your measurement method.

Right now, you've got a "garbage in, garbage out" situation.  The data you've got does not survive simple cross-checks, which tells you that your measurement methods has problems.  What you need to do at this point is go back to the drawing board and devise a better measurement method.  For instance, maybe you can find some way to measure the offset between your clock and the remote machine's clock more precisely, and then adjust for that offset.

But in any case, it's pretty clear that the current measurement method isn't adequate on its own.

Comment: There is no possible way for this to be changed.  The whole point is to present the data to the best of our abilities, without reinventing the protocols at stake.  The data is not wrong: the difference between local and remote clock is correct, and that's all we care about.  Only the absolute points are wrong, which are irrelevant in the grand scheme.  The whole point of the question to find an algorithm to remove these absolute points, leaving the valuable fluctuations for a knowledgeable person to make a decision on which of the two paths — forward or reverse — is responsible for the jitter.

Comment: Also, we cannot control the other host.  That's the whole point of why the time is wrong.  For hosts that we do control, we can already run `ntpd`, and the time will easily be within around 1ms, which is the resolution of ICMP timestamps.  The data above is by no means blatantly wrong, only it's above presentation is.